# Apache Cordova Facebook Javascript SDK issue when navigating to a new html page

Tags: android, apache, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am programming an app in apache cordova and I am using the facebook javascript sdk to communicate with facebook.  My problem is that after I login to facebook when I navigate to a different html file I have to re-initialize the FB.init before I can use it and this causes the previously saved login information to be erased.

This is what I am using to initailize the facebook sdk on my startup page with a javascript linked to it...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
{
    FB.init(
    {
        appId      : '1680542808897877',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });
};

(function (d, s, id)
{
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Then I use window.location = "test.html" to navigate to another html file, which has different js files.  So now if I try to execute a function without initializing the facebook sdk again like this...

```
FB.api('me/picture', function (response)
    {
        var picture = response;
    })
```

I get an error saying FB is not defined.  If I include the facebook initialization code from above in the js files linked to the new html file FB is recognized, but then I get an error saying response is not defined.

Is there a way to initialize the facebook sdk in another js file, but somehow pass the previous login information to it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a js API from facebook and include it in all of your html.

**fbsdk.js**

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({
    appId: '1680542808897877',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.5'
});
};

(function (d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Tried this... logged in to facebook on start up page just fine, then navigated to another page and tried to make a call to the api and get an error back saying "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."